# Accessing variable in script tag with jQuery/cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I am using node.js + cheerio for web scraping.

After requesting the website, I get something like this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
           var x = {name: "Jeff"};
           var y = 4;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I access the variable values through cheerio/jQuery?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could get the `<script>` tag contents as a text a find the variables via regexp:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(html); // your html

const text = $('script')[0].text(); // TODO there might be multiple script tags

// find variable `x` in the text
const matchX = text.match(/var x = (.*);/);
console.log(matchX[1]); // prints "{name: "Jeff"}"

// find variable `y` in the text
const matchY = text.match(/var y = (.*);/);
console.log(matchY[1]); // prints "4"
```

You can get string values like this. Then it depends on what you want to do, if you need those object values, you could use `eval` (but be aware that using `eval` can be dangerous), or you could parse it again via regexp or something (you probably know what values are you looking for).